# Взаимодействие firefox addon с dev/panel

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-extension

Для firefox существует Low-Level API под названием [dev/panel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/dev_panel). Это API позволяет встроиться в панель разработчика.

В документации описан путь взаимодействия аддона с панелью. Я так понял, что панель может только отвечать на postMessage, которые приходят со стороны аддона.

(Под аддоном я понимаю index.js. Под панелью - JS, который подключается к html панели)

Работу аддона необходимо начинать с выбора ф-ии из панели. (Каким-то образом надо вызывать высокоуровневое API из низкоуровневого).

Я реализовал это следующим образом: аддон отправляет сообщение в панель

```
// index.js
onReady: function() {
    // in this function you can communicate
    // with the panel document
    this.postMessage("add-on-ready", [panelSide]);
    //this.postMessage("add-on-ready2", [panelSide]); // This message may be received in logic-panel.js
}
```

Панель запишет полученное сообщение в textarea и отправит ответ аддону только при нажатии некоторую кнопку:

```
//logic-panel.js
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    var toAddon = event.ports[0];
    toAddon.start();

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#log').append(event.data + '\n');
    });

    switch(event.data){
        case "add-on-ready":
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#inspect").click(function(){
                    toAddon.postMessage("inspect");
                });
                $("#exit").click(function(){
                    toAddon.postMessage("exit");
                });

            });
            break;

        default:
            toAddon.postMessage("event.data = " + event.data);
            alert("event.data = " + event.data);
    }
});
```

Аддон обрабатывает ответ. Если была нажата кнопка "inspect", то будут задействованы высокоуровневые API (а именно, PageMod в ф-ии handleClick):

```
addonSide.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log(event.data);
    switch(event.data){
        case "inspect":
            console.log("run inspect");
            handleClick();
            console.log("run inspect end");
            break;

        case "exit":
            console.log("push exit =(");
            break;

        default:
            MyPanel.postMessage("add-on-ready", [panelSide]);       //not work
    }
}


function handleClick() {
    console.log("xpath");
    var data = require("sdk/self").data;

    var pageMod = require('sdk/page-mod').PageMod({
        include: ['*'],
        contentScriptFile: data.url("./addonside/xpath.js"),
        onAttach: function(worker) {
            worker.on('message', function(message) {
                console.log('mouseclick: ' + message);
                ////////////////////////////////
                // this.postMessage('mouseclick: ' + message, [panelSide]); // This message not may be received in logic-panel.js
                ////////////////////////////////
            });
        }
    });
}
```

**Вопрос:** каким образом можно отправить postMessage в панель из ф-ии handleClick()?
Может есть более адекватный способ вызова High-Level APIs с помощью dev/panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему удалось решить так:

В самом начале index.js объявляем `var _MyPanel;`, в `onReady` инициализируем

```
onReady: function() {
    _MyPanel = this;
    _MyPanel.postMessage("add-on-ready", [panelSide]);
}
```

Теперь в функции `handleClick()` можно отправлять сообщения, используя объект `_MyPanel`:

```
function handleClick() {
    console.log("xpath");

    var data = require("sdk/self").data;

    var pageMod = require('sdk/page-mod').PageMod({
        include: ['*'],
        contentScriptFile: data.url("./addonside/xpath.js"),
        onAttach: function(worker) {
            worker.on('message', function(message) {
                console.log('mouseclick: ' + message);
                _MyPanel.postMessage("mouseclick: " + message, [panelSide]);
            });
        }
    });
}
```